# SQL Query with Three Way Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I see there are a few different threads here about SQL joins with three tables. I have a bit of a different issue that is giving me trouble. It may be a DB design issue or maybe I'm not using the join correctly?

Basically I want to get everything from a table called Transactions and join two lookup tables from two lookup fields in Transactions. The catch is that there may not always be a lookup result in the lookup table. Here is my DB schema:

**Transactions** -- Main table I want the data from

- ID
- Transaction_Type
- Prop_ID
- ... other irrelevant fields

**Property** -- Lookup table

- ID
- ... other irrelevant fields

**Transaction_Type**  -- Lookup table

- ID
- .. other irrelevant fields

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Transactions` 
Join TransactionType on Transactions.Type_ID = TransactionType.ID 
Join Property on Transactions.Prop_ID = Property.ID  
ORDER BY `Transactions`.`ID`  DESC
```

This gives my 99% of what I want. The catch is that it does not return the records from the Transaction table when Transactions.Prop_ID does not have a matching Property.ID. I have some Transactions with a Prop_ID of 0 which is meant to signal they are in a general category - not tied to a property.

My issue is that I have all of these transactions that go with a property. Except there are some that are for the business as a whole (phone bill, internet, etc.). I feel that they should really go in the transactions table but they won't join to a property in this query. At the same time it also seems wrong to add a general record in the Property table because that will break several other things.

Any advice? I am early on and can change my schema if needed? I would rather do it the right way while I still can. Thanks!

Comment: You need `left join` instead of `join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the final solution, but start by using left joins

```
SELECT Transactions.*, 
  FROM `Transactions` 
  LEFT JOIN TransactionType on Transactions.Type_ID = TransactionType.ID 
  LEFT JOIN Property on Transactions.Prop_ID = Property.ID  
ORDER BY `Transactions`.`ID`  DESC
```

that way, the transactions whose Type_ID doesn't have a match in TransactionType table will show TransactionType.ID as NULL instead of not bringing anything at all. Same goes for the Property table. Rows without a match in Property.ID will show up with Property.ID NULL.

This can help you find, for example, every transaction that your former query was leaving out due to the absence of a matching record in Property or TransactionType

```
SELECT Transactions.*, 
  FROM `Transactions` 
  LEFT JOIN TransactionType on Transactions.Type_ID = TransactionType.ID 
  LEFT JOIN Property on Transactions.Prop_ID = Property.ID  
WHERE (Property.ID is null OR TransactionType.ID is NULL)
ORDER BY `Transactions`.`ID`  DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Three table JOIN syntax in SQL:

SELECT t1.col, t3.col FROM table1 join table2 ON table1.primarykey = table2.foreignkey
                                  join table3 ON table2.primarykey = table3.foreignkey